# Parse multiple date formats into a single format

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have one column called published (date). As you can see, it has multiple date formats and also nan values. I would like to skip nan values, convert all the other formats to %Y-%-%d, and ignore the one that has the only year.

I tried df['publish_time']=pd.to_datetime(df['publish_time']) 
and also things like:

```
fmt=['%Y-%m-%d', '%d-%m-%Y', '%d/%m/%Y',
              '%Y-%d-%m', '%Y-%d-%b', '%d-%b-%Y', '%d/%b/%Y','Year: %d; month','month: 
               %d;Year','%Y','%b %d %Y','%b %Y %d']
```

but I could not solve it. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Here is that column:

```
published

2014 Jul 22
2003 Aug
2019 Nov 26
2012-12-07
2020 Jan 21
2015-01-01
2010-11-30
2007-05-10
2020
2012-02-29
2016 Apr 19
2006-12-31
2013 Jun 27
2019 Jun 19
2015 Jun 12
2006 Jun-Dec
2006-07-31
nan
2017-04-15
2016 May 22
2020 Feb
2017 May 6
2020 Mar 11
2013-04-30
2020-03-07
nan
2018
```

Comment: Ideally, this should be addressed before it gets to this point; when you end up with this kind of dirty data, going back and figuring out how to clean it at ingestion time is usually the right approach going forward (and if this is all coming from a single source, drop them, and if they're charging you, it's time to demand your money back). At this point you should expect incorrect conversion results for y/d/m, y/m/d, and possibly other formats, and you have so much data that's just meaningless... really, look back up the chain and try to fix the problems as it's coming in.

Answer (score 2):

First was added 2 new formats to `fmt` list:

```
fmt=['%Y-%m-%d', '%d-%m-%Y', '%d/%m/%Y',
     '%Y-%d-%m', '%Y-%d-%b', '%d-%b-%Y', '%d/%b/%Y','Year: %d; month',
     'month: %d;Year','%Y','%b %d %Y','%b %Y %d',
     '%Y %b %d', '%Y %b']
```

Then in list comprehension convert column to datetimes, parameter `errors='coerce'` is for non matched values to missing values. Last join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html).

Last because possible multiple values per rows because `dd/mm/YYYY` vs `mm/dd/YYYY` formats (not sure if month of day) is used back filling with select first column. It means what format is first in list it is selected with high priority.

```
dfs = [pd.to_datetime(df['publish_time'], format=f, errors='coerce') for f in fmt]
df['publish_time1']= pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
```

---

```
print (df)
    publish_time publish_time1
0    2014 Jul 22    2014-07-22
1       2003 Aug    2003-08-01
2    2019 Nov 26    2019-11-26
3     2012-12-07    2012-12-07
4    2020 Jan 21    2020-01-21
5     2015-01-01    2015-01-01
6     2010-11-30    2010-11-30
7     2007-05-10    2007-05-10
8           2020    2020-01-01
9     2012-02-29    2012-02-29
10   2016 Apr 19    2016-04-19
11    2006-12-31    2006-12-31
12   2013 Jun 27    2013-06-27
13   2019 Jun 19    2019-06-19
14   2015 Jun 12    2015-06-12
15  2006 Jun-Dec           NaT
16    2006-07-31    2006-07-31
17           NaN           NaT
18    2017-04-15    2017-04-15
19   2016 May 22    2016-05-22
20      2020 Feb    2020-02-01
21    2017 May 6    2017-05-06
22   2020 Mar 11    2020-03-11
23    2013-04-30    2013-04-30
24    2020-03-07    2020-03-07
25           NaN           NaT
26          2018    2018-01-01
```

Comment: many thanks! I tried just, it gives me lots of NaT. I 'm checking now and try to find if my fmt covered all those formats.

Comment: I 've just noticed format such as "2019 Nov 26" returned to NaT value. What is this format when it has year, three letters of the month, date?thanks!

Comment: @almo - It is `'%Y %b %d'`, I add 2 new formats to end of your list

Comment: @almo - Also not sure, but `'Year: %d; month'` is parsing `'Year: 10; month'` data - with texts `Year` and `month`

Comment: sorry, have to ask one last question.  How can get have published only have year and month, like %Y%m, I didn't find a way to alter your f value:)

Comment: @almo - Can you give me some example?

Comment: @almo - `%Y%m` is `202003` - '2020-03-01'

Comment: 2019 Nov 16 to only 2019-06, because I have many rows that have only years and I don't want to have them all set to Jan.01. So to make a balance, have only year and month as the final format

Comment: @almo - Itis problem, because datetimes with no days not exist in python

Comment: I tried to add one line f='%Y%m' before the line of for f in fmt,  but it did not help.

Comment: @almo - Yes, because if want all values converted to datetimes it not exist like `YYYY-MM` datetime, alwas minimal year, month, day. is required for datetime in python

Comment: @jerazel, I guess I will skip those rows that have only years, then split the other rows to remove the date. :)