# Parse multiple date formats into a single format-further question

Tags: python, pandas, date

Update: The question is now solved :)

I have asked one [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60831665/parse-multiple-date-formats-into-a-single-format) before. That answer was great. But now, the dataset gets more complicated.

Based on the original answer, I tried like this:

```
 fmt=['%Y-%m-%d', '%d-%m-%Y', '%d/%m/%Y','%Y-%d-%m', '%Y-%d-%b', '%d-%b-%Y', 
  '%d/%b/%Y','Year: %d; month','month: %d;Year','%Y','%b %d %Y','%b %Y %d',
     '%Y/%m/%d','%Y/%d/%m','%Y%m']

 dfs = [pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format=f, errors='coerce') for f in fmt]

 df['Date']= pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
```

And it gave me more than 4000 NaN values in df.date column. And if I delete all those NaN values, that's too much.  When I tracked down the date column, those NaN values were caused by these rows:

```
20050
2014/17/0
2006/0/5
2005-3-0
2006-18-0
2004/24/7
```

Any ideas about how should I deal with them? I 'm thinking to replace those month/date with zero to one like this:

```
 20500           =====> 2005-01-01
 2014/17/0       =====> 2004-01-17
 2006/0/5        =====> 2006-01-05
 2005-3-0        =====> 2005-03-01
 2006-18-0       =====> 2006-01-18
```

Note: Some rows the date was in Year/month/date format whereas the other rows could be Year/date/month or simply YearDate

Thank you for your help!

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Here are some printed out dateformat:

```
2002-11-25
2001-11-25
2002-9-27
2001-2-24
2002-9-20
2001-5-3
2002-2-28
200510
2004/19/10
2006-11-01
2004/22/3
20055
2004/28/4
2006-6-01
20057
20050
2006-10-01
2004/17/0
2006-6-01
2006-3-01
2001-4-4
2001-6-19
2003/16/11
20054
20065
20057
2006-2-01
2003/0/1
2002-1-27
20057
2006-5-01
20065
2006-0-01
2006-9-01
2002-6-28
20054
2001-1-25
2006-0-01
2006-3-01
2006-1-01
2006-1-01
2004/5/2
2003/3/4
2002-10-13
2006-6-01
2004/24/1
2002-11-11
2001-4-9
2003/21/4
2002-4-1
2004/24/7
```

With jezrael's solution, I have successfully reduced NaT values from more than 4000 rows to only around 300 rows. The data format in those 300 rows were like the follows:

```
        Date        Date1
238     2001-01-0     NaT
249     2001-1-0      NaT
277     2001-2-0      NaT
506     2002-1-0      NaT
535     2002-4-0      NaT    
58510   2001-1-0      NaT
58516   2001-1-0      NaT
58779   2002-3-0      NaT
58888   2001-3-0      NaT
58889   2002-8-0      NaT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem not valid dates, mainly because `0` are processing like `1`. So solution is repalce this values, `$` is for match end of string:

```
d = {'/0$':'/01','/0/':'/01/','-0-':'-01-'}
df['Date'] = df['Date'].replace(d, regex=True)

#for replace formats like 20050 to 200501
m = df['Date'].str.len().eq(5) & df['Date'].str.endswith('0')

df['Date'] = df['Date'].mask(m, df['Date'] + '1')
```

You can still looking for no matched values like used for check data in original solution:

```
fmt=['%Y-%m-%d', '%d-%m-%Y', '%d/%m/%Y','%Y-%d-%m', '%Y-%d-%b', '%d-%b-%Y', 
  '%d/%b/%Y','Year: %d; month','month: %d;Year','%Y','%b %d %Y','%b %Y %d',
     '%Y/%m/%d','%Y/%d/%m','%Y%m']

dfs = [pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format=f, errors='coerce') for f in fmt]

df['Date1']= pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
 
df = df[df['Date1'].isna()]
print (df)
         Date Date1
15      20050   NaT
17  2004/17/0   NaT
27   2003/0/1   NaT
32  2006-0-01   NaT
37  2006-0-01   NaT
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. How should I run it? With that fmt, all the invalid format was converted to NaT. Should I run your above code first before running fmt?

Comment: before my or @Quang solution.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael, with your suggestion, the NaT values have been reduced from more than 4000 to 1100. When the length of the whole dataset is more than 450,000, I guess I could remove the left 1100 NaT rows: ) Or what do you suggest

Comment: @almo - Maybe some another replacement should be used. I add solution for find them

Comment: @almo - I add my test of original data before my solution, is possible check it and what is more repetive patterns? I hope NaT should be reduced.

Comment: Thank you so much. @jezrael. I could not double vote:D . With your updated suggestion, I got only 389 left, but I 'm quite satisfied. Thank you! Perfect solution

Comment: Perfect. Thank you @jezrael

Comment: The left error dates had zero in days.  I suppose it could be fixed by adding one more line  like this m = df['Date'].str.len().eq(7). But some months have double digits and some have only one digit, so I will ignore those :)

Answer (score 1):

You are better off using `fillna`:

```
# initialize with all `nan`
out = pd.Series(pd.NaT, df.index)

# list of formats
fmt=['%Y-%m-%d', '%d-%m-%Y', '%d/%m/%Y','%Y-%d-%m', '%Y-%d-%b', '%d-%b-%Y', 
'%d/%b/%Y','Year: %d; month','month: %d;Year','%Y','%b %d %Y','%b %Y %d',
 '%Y/%m/%d','%Y/%d/%m','%Y%m']

# loop through format,
# update the series with valid dates for that format
for f in fmt:
    out = out.fillna(pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format=f, errors='coerce'))

df['Date'] = out
```

Comment: Thanks Quang Hoang. When I use fillna, what's the value it would be? Or maybe, I can try it. One minute :)

Comment: On the second note, your sample data contains invalid dates, for all of the formats. So you would get all `NaN` values. If that's intended, I'll be deleting this answer.

Comment: I would like to minimize those NaN values @Quang Hoang. I do know some formats are invalid such as 2004/24/7. It's just strange, I still get nearly the same amount of NaN value after running your code. In your answer, the first line, should I write df.index or df.date.index?

Comment: `df.index` and `df.date.index` are the same thing. Yet, `2004/24/7` was in fact the only thing that is not `NaN` in your example.

Comment: Hi! I need to rerun and check again. It may take sometime. Because now the NaT still exist. If it solve the problem, I will accept the answer. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: those NaT remain :(. I updated my question (pasted some dates from the dateset.